# Waiting for invokeLater() to be called

Tags: java, sleep, polling, eventqueue, invokeandwait

Is there a more elegant way to do what I'm doing below?  That is, is there a more elegant way than polling and sleeping, polling and sleeping, and so on to know when a `Runnable.run()` method has been called via `invokeLater()`?

```
private int myMethod() {
    final WaitForEventQueue waitForQueue = new WaitForEventQueue();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(waitForQueue);
    while (!waitForQueue.done) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

private class WaitForEventQueue implements Runnable {
    private boolean done;

    public void run() {
        // Let all Swing text stuff finish.
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For whatever it's worth this code fails on two levels: (1) it is not thread-safe because the waiting thread may never "see" the update to `done` (see the Java Memory Model for V5+), and (2) polling is generally a bad solution, especially in a language that has such an easy wait/notify mechanism (see Object.wait, et al).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to wait, why not call [invokeAndWait](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) rather than implement it yourself?

Comment: Because invokeAndWait causes deadlocks and livelocks and basically eats kittens for breakfast.

Comment: @Trejkaz, not really my experience, but I'm sure the suggested code wouldn't be an improvement.

Comment: Probably not, although I do wonder. Because it isn't using a lock, maybe it won't deadlock. However, I do think it will exhibit this other issue where it isn't deadlocked but never returns.

Answer (score 5):

A better way would be to use a [`FutureTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) (which implements Runnable and Future) and override its done() event to do something when finished.

Also, start this as a separate thread (or use an [`Executor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)) if it's not doing GUI manipulation, rather than using the AWT EventQueue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for the thread to finish, why not just have the UI display a spinner or something, and have the thread call an event when it is done.

Comment: Hi Justin,  

Thanks for the suggestion, but could you be more specific (i.e. show some sample code) as far as the "thread call[ing] an event when it is done" part?